# Spring-Security: MySQL JDBC Authentication fails

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I am manipulating an open source project in [this repo](https://github.com/salman-/ignit-QA). The file `bank.sql` is the schema of the database in mysql. Here is the `pom.xml`:

```
 <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/juli -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>juli</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.11</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
       <groupId>jstl</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
       <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
       <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.2</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

I have a login form as below:

```
    <form name="loginForm" class="form-login"
        action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="POST">
        <h2>Please sign in</h2>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="alert alert-info">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit">Login</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />

    </form>
```

The file `Spring-Security.xml` is as below:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/change**" access="hasRole('ROLE_NEWUSER')" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="bankCustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="bankCustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="ee.mikkelsaar.bank.security.MyUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="sha" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, a.authority from users u, authorities a where u.username = a.username and u.username =?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:import resource="spring-datasource.xml" />

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder">
      <beans:constructor-arg value="sha" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

And there is a bean to obtain the datasource to provide it for `Authentication-manager` such as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am sure the MySQL Server is running on port 3306 well.

The correct credential is `username:Tom` and `password:Tom` but everytime I try to login with them it fails. I am wondering, what is wrong with my authentication process?

How can i fix it?

I guess, maybe the datasource bean is not created correctly, but i have no idea how to check it?

Update:

When i add the `<http security="none" pattern="/login"/>` to my `Spring-Security.xml` it complains with

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported for (username, password) `(Tom, tom)`, which is not a valid credential. But for a valid credential like `(Tom,Tom)` is still navigates to the login page again.
```

but it happens

Comment: First of all, what does it mean: 'it fails'? Do you get some error (if yes, please post the stack trace)? Or you just get redirected to the same login page again? Second: I don't see security disable for your login page in your config. Try adding the following `<http security="none" pattern="/login"/>` to your `Spring-Security.xml`, right above your existing `<http>` element.

Comment: Also, try enabling DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.security` package

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy by failure, i meant it navigates to the login page again. I have updated my question with your answer

Comment: can u clone the repository and investigate the issue?
it's a small app.

Comment: What about trying the DB connection inside your IDE? Just to make sure it's working properly..

Answer (score 8):

First of all, in Spring Security prior to version 4, default parameter names are `j_username` and `j_password` (like in the post you mentioned) and not `username`/`password`.

In Spring Security 4, the default names are `username` and `password`, but the default URL to which `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` binds is `/login` and not `/j_spring_security_check`.

So in all Spring Security versions, your URL and parameter names combination does not match the defaults.

Here is an example of how username-password authentication against a database may be configured: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ (for Spring Security 3.x)

Another example (much more short and simple), for Spring Security 4: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

## How the parameters are passed

Basically, if you have a form-based authentication, it works like this:

1. User tries to access some URL that requires authentication; user lacks that authentication
2. Spring Security redirects the user to a login page
3. **User enters login and password on that page and submits it; in the default configuration in Spring Security versions before 4, username is submitted as `j_username` and password as `j_password` to `/j_spring_security_check`**
4. **Spring Security-supplied `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` processes submissions to `/j_spring_security_check` URL. Once it gets a request (from login form), it extracts the parameters (username/password), packs them into `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and feeds it to `AuthenticationManager` for authentication.**
5. `AuthenticationManager` checks access (JDBC can be used to check against a database, for example)
6. **If the authentication is successful (user exists with the supplied name, password matches), the result `Authentication` is constructed (which contains information about roles), saved, and `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is invoked; it gets that `Authentication` result**
7. After authentication succeeds, the user is redirected back to the URL he tried to access on step 1, and **only here a business logic controller will be executed**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one change, try for 
and for  Authentication-manager
 Authentication-manager

```
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="daoAuthProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>



<beans:bean id="daoAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService">
            <beans:ref bean="userDetailsService" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource">
            <beans:ref bean="coreDataSource" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>
                SELECT username,password as password FROM userdetails WHERE
                password != '' and username= ? 
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>
                SELECT username,authority FROM authorities JOIN userdetails ON authorities.user_id = userdetails.user_id ..
                WHERE userdetails.username= ? and
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>


<security:http pattern="/admin/admin.jsp" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/**/*.js" security="none" /> ..


        <security:custom-filter ref="formAuthFilter"
            after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <beans:bean id="formAuthFilter"
        class="com.sca.security.SCAAuthenticationProcessingFilter">

        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authManager" />
        <beans:property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
            ref="authFailureHandler" /> <!-- define authFailureHandler -->
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            ref="authSuccessHandler" /><!-- define authSuccessHandler -->
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
<!-- define userDAO, globalFilter-->

        </beans:property>


    </beans:bean>
```

This is what exactly you are asking for. Please do not forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied or ask more if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your spring security config is right.
The key for resolving this problem is understanding spring-security csrf protection strategy.More detail you can see [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.java][1] source code.

Server side CSRF token repository is session based. It will generated when you first get request. Get request will not trigger CSRF validation, so it can pass.But if your client side token is wrong or empty  server will prevent your any modify request(.eg POST,PUT,DELETE), response 403 state code.

Your error is caused by that your page is holding an old csrf token in the hidden input, and every login request is forwarded to an error page, so your client side csrf token can not be refreshed.

So simply, you can try refresh you login page and try login again.